# Are variables thread safe when readonly?

Tags: swift

```
class MyClass
    let myString = "string"

    func myFunc() -> String {
       return self.myString
    }
}
```

Given that `myString` is never changed, is `myFunc` thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is not sufficient to make a reference read-only to make a class thread-safe. You need to make sure that the referenced object cannot be mutated.

Your function is thread safe. However, making `myString` read-only is only part of the reason: the other part is the fact that `myString` is of an immutable type.

For example, this `MyClass` is not thread-safe, despite `myData` being read-only:

```
class MyClass
    let myData = Mutable()

    func myFunc() -> Mutable {
       return self.myData
    }
}

class Mutable {
    var array : [String]
    func add(s:String) {
        array.apppend(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `Mutable` has no functions and `array` is guaranteed to never change? Would `myFunc` be thread-safe?

Comment: @tumber033 If `myData` has no functions and it data never changes, then it is effectively immutable, making `myFunc` thread-safe again. Moreover, if you make all mutable functions on `myData` non-public, `MyClass` would be thread-safe outside of your module, while remaining potentially not thread-safe inside your module, where you have access to mutating functions.